# Composing rotations and translations given in local coordinate system to determine a time series of global orientations and positions

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors, linear-transformations, quaternions

I have a time series of camera locations $L_i$ = $\langle Q_i, P_i \rangle$, with each camera location having an initially unknown global orientation quaternion $Q_i$ and global position vector $P_i$. Between each pair of adjacent camera locations $L_i$ and $L_{i+1}$, there is a known mapping $\langle R_i, T_i \rangle$ consisting of a local rotation quaternion $R_i$ and a local translation vector $T_i$ that rotate and then translate the camera from $L_{i+1}$ back to the local coordinate system of $L_i$ (i.e. $L_i$ is fixed, and the local transformations map or register $L_{i+1}$ to $L_i$). Given a point $X_{i+1}$ representing the coordinates of a specific point $X$ in the local coordinate system of $L_{i+1}$, the coordinates of $X$ may be found for the local coordinate system of $L_i$ using:

$X_i = R_i X_{i+1} R_i^{-1} + T_i$

and therefore,

$X_{i-1} = R_{i-1} (R_i X_{i+1} R_i^{-1} + T_i) R_{i-1}^{-1} + T_{i-1}$.

This rule may be applied iteratively to eventually find $X_0$, which is the coordinates of $X_{i+1}$ in the global coordinate system.

However, applying these transformations backwards, from the last camera location to the first, for a series of 3D point clouds $X_i^j$ captured from each camera location $L_i$, is an $O(N^2)$ operation in the number of camera locations $N$, since all points in each point cloud for a camera location $L_i$ have to be transformed by all $\langle R_j, T_j \rangle$ for $0 \le j \lt i$. Therefore, I would like to invert these transformations so that the "inverse" of each local transform can simply be concatenated to produce a new set of transformations $\langle Q_i, P_i \rangle$ that directly transform a point $X_i$ to $X_0$ (i.e. that directly transform from the coordinate system of $L_i$ into the coordinate system of $L_0$) via the single transform:

$X_0 = Q_i X_i Q_i^{-1} + P_i$

**The core question:** How can $Q_{i}$ and $P_{i}$ be computed from $\langle R_j, T_j \rangle$, for $0 \le j \lt i\,$? (Note that it is fine to assume that $L_0$ is already in the global coordinate system, rather than $L_{N-1}$, when working from the beginning of the list of transformations, i.e. $Q_0$ is the identity and $P_0$ is zero.)

The problem is that the transformations are defined as a chain back from the last camera position to the first, but I need the cumulative concatenation of transforms from the first camera position to the last. I think this requires inverting the relative order of rotation and translation: given $A_i X_i A_i^{-1} + B_i$, how do you find the equivalent transformation expressed as $C_i (X_i + D_i) C_i^{-1}$?

Comment: To simplify my answer: use $P_{i+1} = P_i + Q_i^\prime T_i Q_i$, because you want to invert the rotation $Q_i$.

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution and it's still not working either for some reason, but I'm sure I have something wrong with my implementaiton.

Comment: The inverse of transformation$$X_0 = Q_i X_i Q_i^{-1} + P_i$$is$$X_i = Q_i^{-1} ( X_0 - P_i ) Q_i = Q_i^{-1} X_0 Q_i - Q_i^{-1} P_i Q_i$$where $Q_i$ is an unit quaternion and $X_0$, $X_i$, and $P_i$ are vectors.  If $$L_i = R_i L_{i+1} R_i^{-1} + T_i$$then$$L_{i+1} = R_i^{-1} (L_i - T_i) R_i = R_i^{-1} L_i R_i - R_i^{-1} T_i R_i$$where $L_i$, $L_{i+1}$, and $T_i$ are vectors, and $R_i$ is an unit quaternion.

Comment: In your question, the expression for $X_{i-1}$ is missing a $R_{i-1}^{i-1}$ just after the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks, I somehow missed the idea that quaternion multiplication distributes over vector addition. That's obvious in hindsight!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third take.  Stop changing the definitions! :)

We have a sequence of cumulative rotation unit quaternions $R_i$ and cumulative translations $T_i$ in each local coordinate system, with $Q_i$ describing the rotation from the global coordinate system to local coordinate system at step $i$, and $P_i$ being the sum total translations up to and including step $i$ in the global coordinate system:

$$Q_i = Q_{i-1} R_{i-1} \tag{1a}\label{None1a}$$
or equivalently
$$Q_i = Q_{i+1} R_i^{-1} \tag{1b}\label{None1b}$$
and
$$P_i = P_{i-1} + Q_{i-1} T_{i-1} Q_{i-1}^{-1} \tag{2a}\label{None2a}$$
or equivalently
$$P_i = P_{i+1} - Q_i T_i Q_i^{-1} \tag{2b}\label{None2b}$$

We can use $\eqref{None1a}$ or $\eqref{None1b}$ to construct $Q_0^\prime, Q_1^\prime, \dots, Q_{N-1}^\prime, Q_{N}^\prime$.  With $\eqref{None1a}$, set $Q_N^\prime = 1$ and iterate $i = N-1, N-2, \dots, 2, 1, 0$.  With $\eqref{None1b}$, set $Q_0\prime = 0$ and iterate $i = 1, 2, \dots, N-1, N$.

Then, fix $Q_k = 1$ (where $0 \le k \le N$), by iterating
$$Q_i = Q_k^{\prime -1} Q_i^\prime, \quad \forall i \tag{3}\label{None3}$$

After you have the orientations, you can calculate the total translations $P_i$ using
$$P_0^\prime = \vec{0}, \quad P_i^\prime = P_{i-1}^\prime + Q_{i-1} T_{i-1} Q_{i-1}^{-1} \tag{4a}\label{None4a}$$
or
$$P_N^\prime = \vec{0}, \quad P_i^\prime = P_{i+1}^\prime - Q_i T_i Q_i^{-1} \tag{4b}\label{None4b}$$
which will yield the same translations except for a constant difference.  Again, to fix $P_k = \vec{0}$ for some $0 \le k \le N$, iterate
$$P_i = P_i^\prime - P_k^\prime, \quad \forall i \tag{5}\label{None5}$$

As you can clearly see, this has $O(N)$ time complexity.

If $k = N$, use the $(a)$ methods; and if $k = 0$, the $(b)$ methods. This way the fixup is an identity operation, and can be skipped.

Note that with the fixup pass, both $(a)$ and $(b)$ work for all $k$, including $k = 0$ and $k = N$.  Choosing one over the other is just an optimization.

---

Here is an example Python3 program, that implements two helper classes, `Vector` and `Versor`, and implements the above logic.  (If you save this as `example.py`, you can use `pydoc3 example` to see the API it provides.  It is in Public Domain, and you can use the classes in your own scripts if you put it in the same directory, and add `from example import Vector, Versor`.)

```
"""3D Euclidean vector class 'Vector', and unit quaternion class 'Versor'
   -- a playground for experimenting with rotations in 3D"""

# SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0

from math import sqrt, pi, sin, cos, atan2

class Vector(tuple):
    """3D Cartesian vector type"""

    FORMAT = "(%8.5f,%8.5f,%8.5f)"

    def __new__(cls, x, y, z):
        """Create a new vector"""
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (float(x), float(y), float(z)))

    @property
    def x(self):
        """x coordinate"""
        return self[0]

    @property
    def y(self):
        """y coordinate"""
        return self[1]

    @property
    def z(self):
        """z coordinate"""
        return self[2]

    @property
    def norm(self):
        """Euclidean length"""
        return sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2])

    @property
    def normsqr(self):
        """Euclidean length squared"""
        return self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2]

    @property
    def unit_vector(self):
        """Scaled to unit length"""
        n = sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2])
        if n > 0:
            return tuple.__new__(Vector, (self[0]/n, self[1]/n, self[2]/n))
        else:
            return tuple.__new__(Vector, (0, 0, 0))

    def perpendicular_to(self, other):
        """Part perpendicular to another vector"""
        nn = float(other[0])**2 + float(other[1])**2 + float(other[2])**2
        if nn > 0:
            d = (self[0]*other[0] + self[1]*other[1] + self[2]*other[2]) / nn
            return tuple.__new__(Vector, (self[0] - d*other[0],
                                          self[1] - d*other[1],
                                          self[2] - d*other[2]))
        else:
            return tuple.__new__(Vector, (0, 0, 0))

    def transform(self, matrix, translate=(0,0,0), pretranslate=(0,0,0)):
        """Transform this point by rotation matrix and translation"""
        curr = Vector(self[0]+pretranslate[0], self[1]+pretranslate[1], self[2]+pretranslate[2])
        post = Vector(translate)
        return Vector(matrix[0][0]*curr[0] + matrix[0][1]*curr[1] + matrix[0][2]*curr[2] + post[0],
                      matrix[1][0]*curr[0] + matrix[1][1]*curr[1] + matrix[1][2]*curr[2] + post[1],
                      matrix[2][0]*curr[0] + matrix[2][1]*curr[1] + matrix[2][2]*curr[2] + post[2])

    def __str__(self):
        """Conversion to string"""
        return Vector.FORMAT % self

    def __abs__(self):
        """Absolute value is the Euclidean length"""
        return sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2])

    def __neg__(self):
        """Opposite vector, negation"""
        return tuple.__new__(Vector, (-self[0], -self[1], -self[2]))

    def __bool__(self):
        """Nonzero vectors are considered True, zero vectors False"""
        return (self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2] > 0)

    def __add__(self, other):
        """Vector addition"""
        return tuple.__new__(Vector, (self[0]+other[0], self[1]+other[1], self[2]+other[2]))

    def __radd__(self, other):
        """Vector addition"""
        return tuple.__new__(Vector, (other[0]+self[0], other[1]+self[1], other[2]+self[2]))

    def __sub__(self, other):
        """Vector subtraction"""
        return tuple.__new__(Vector, (self[0]-other[0], self[1]-other[1], self[2]-other[2]))
        
    def __radd__(self, other):
        """Vector subtraction"""
        return tuple.__new__(Vector, (other[0]-self[0], other[1]-self[1], other[2]-self[2]))

    def __mul__(self, scalar):
        if isinstance(scalar, (int, float)):
            return tuple.__new__(Vector, (self[0]*scalar, self[1]*scalar, self[2]*scalar))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __rmul__(self, scalar):
        if isinstance(scalar, (int, float)):
            return tuple.__new__(Vector, (scalar*self[0], scalar*self[1], scalar*self[2]))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __truediv__(self, scalar):
        if isinstance(scalar, (int, float)):
            return tuple.__new__(Vector, (self[0]/scalar, self[1]/scalar, self[2]/scalar))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __rtruediv__(self, ignored):
        return NotImplemented

    def __or__(self, other):
        """Dot product, a | b"""    
        if isinstance(other, (list, tuple)) and len(other) == 3:
            return self[0]*other[0] + self[1]*other[1] + self[2]*other[2]
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def dot(self, other):
        """Dot product"""
        return self[0]*other[0] + self[1]*other[1] + self[2]*other[2]

    def __xor__(self, other):
        """Cross product, a ^ b"""
        if isinstance(other, (list, tuple)) and len(other) == 3:
            return tuple.__new__(Vector, ( self[1]*other[2] - self[2]*other[1],
                                           self[2]*other[0] - self[0]*other[2],
                                           self[0]*other[1] - self[1]*other[0] ))
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def cross(self, other):
        """Cross product"""
        return tuple.__new__(Vector, ( self[1]*other[2] - self[2]*other[1],
                                       self[2]*other[0] - self[0]*other[2],
                                       self[0]*other[1] - self[1]*other[0] ))


class Versor(tuple):
    """Unit quaternion type describing an orientation or a rotation"""

    FORMAT = "(%8.5f;%8.5f,%8.5f,%8.5f)"

    def __new__(cls, w, x, y, z):
        """Create a new versor"""
        w = float(w)
        x = float(x)
        y = float(y)
        z = float(z)
        n = sqrt(w*w + x*x + y*y + z*z)
        if n == 0:
            w = 1
            x = 0
            y = 0
            z = 0
        elif n != 1:
            w /= n
            x /= n
            y /= n
            z /= n
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (w, x, y, z))

    @classmethod
    def from_axis_angle(cls, axis, angle):
        """Create a versor from an axis and angle in degrees"""
        x = float(axis[0])
        y = float(axis[1])
        z = float(axis[2])
        h = angle * pi / 360.0
        n = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)
        if n == 0:
            return tuple.__new__(cls, (1, 0, 0, 0))
        s, c = sin(h), cos(h)
        return tuple.__new__(cls, (c, s*x/n, s*y/n, s*z/n))

    def __str__(self):
        """Conversion to string"""
        return Versor.FORMAT % self

    def __abs__(self):
        return sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2])

    def __neg__(self):
        return Versor(-self[0], -self[1], -self[2], -self[3])

    def __mul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return (self[0]*other, self[1]*other, self[2]*other, self[3]*other)            
        elif isinstance(other, (list, tuple)) and len(other) == 4:
            return (self[0]*other[0] - self[1]*other[1] - self[2]*other[2] - self[3]*other[3],
                    self[0]*other[1] + self[1]*other[0] + self[2]*other[3] - self[3]*other[2],
                    self[0]*other[2] - self[1]*other[3] + self[2]*other[0] + self[3]*other[1],
                    self[0]*other[3] + self[1]*other[2] - self[2]*other[1] + self[3]*other[0])
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    def __rmul__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, (int, float)):
            return (other*self[0], other*self[1], other*self[2], other*self[3])
        elif isinstance(other, (list, tuple)) and len(other) == 4:
            return (other[0]*self[0] - other[1]*self[1] - other[2]*self[2] - other[3]*self[3],
                    other[0]*self[1] + other[1]*self[0] + other[2]*self[3] - other[3]*self[2],
                    other[0]*self[2] - other[1]*self[3] + other[2]*self[0] + other[3]*self[1],
                    other[0]*self[3] + other[1]*self[2] - other[2]*self[1] + other[3]*self[0])
        else:
            return NotImplemented

    @property
    def w(self):
        """Versor real component"""
        return self[0]

    @property
    def x(self):
        """Versor vector x component"""
        return self[1]

    @property
    def y(self):
        """Versor vector y component"""
        return self[2]

    @property
    def z(self):
        """Versor vector z component"""
        return self[3]

    @property
    def axis(self):
        """Rotation unit axis vector"""
        n = sqrt(self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2] + self[3]*self[3])
        if n > 0:
            return Vector(self[1]/n, self[2]/n, self[3]/n)
        else:
            return Vector(0, 0, 0)

    @property
    def angle(self):
        """Rotation angle, in degrees"""
        n = sqrt(self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2] + self[3]*self[3])
        if n > 0:
            return atan2(n, self[0]) * 360.0 / pi

    @property
    def normalized(self):
        """Versor normalized to unit length"""
        n = sqrt(self[0]*self[0] + self[1]*self[1] + self[2]*self[2] + self[3]*self[3])
        if n == 0:
            return tuple.__new__(Versor, (1, 0, 0, 0))
        elif n != 1:
            return tuple.__new__(Versor, (self[0]/n, self[1]/n, self[2]/n, self[3]/n))
        else:
            return self

    @property
    def inverse(self):
        """Inverse of this versor"""
        return tuple.__new__(Versor, (self[0], -self[1], -self[2], -self[3]))

    @property
    def matrix(self):
        """Rotation matrix corresponding to this versor"""
        c01 = 2*self[0]*self[1]
        c02 = 2*self[0]*self[2]
        c03 = 2*self[0]*self[3]
        c11 = 2*self[1]*self[1]
        c12 = 2*self[1]*self[2]
        c13 = 2*self[1]*self[3]
        c22 = 2*self[2]*self[2]
        c23 = 2*self[2]*self[3]
        c33 = 2*self[3]*self[3]
        return ( Vector(1-c22-c33, c12-c03, c13+c02),
                 Vector(c12+c03, 1-c11-c33, c23-c01),
                 Vector(c13-c02, c23+c01, 1-c11-c22) )

    def rotate(self, other):
        """For vector v, q.rotate(v) calculates q v q^-1 .
           For quaternion p, q.rotate(p) calculates q p."""
        if isinstance(other, (list, tuple)) and len(other) == 3:
            x = float(other[0])
            y = float(other[1])
            z = float(other[2])
            c00 = self[0]*self[0]
            c11 = self[1]*self[1]
            c22 = self[2]*self[2]
            c33 = self[3]*self[3]
            c01 = 2*self[0]*self[1]
            c02 = 2*self[0]*self[2]
            c03 = 2*self[0]*self[3]
            c12 = 2*self[1]*self[2]
            c13 = 2*self[1]*self[3]
            c23 = 2*self[2]*self[3]
            return Vector(x*(c00+c11-c22-c33) + y*(c12-c03) + z*(c02+c13),
                          x*(c03+c12) + y*(c00-c11+c22-c33) + z*(c23-c01),
                          x*(c13-c02) + y*(c01+c23) + z*(c00-c11-c22+c33))
        elif isinstance(other, (list, tuple)) and len(other) == 4:
            return Versor(self[0]*other[0] - self[1]*other[1] - self[2]*other[2] - self[3]*other[3],
                          self[0]*other[1] + self[1]*other[0] + self[2]*other[3] - self[3]*other[2],
                          self[0]*other[2] - self[1]*other[3] + self[2]*other[0] + self[3]*other[1],
                          self[0]*other[3] + self[1]*other[2] - self[2]*other[1] + self[3]*other[0])
        else:
            raise ValueError("Cannot rotate a %s" % str(type(other)))

    def rotated_by(self, other):
        """For quaternion p, q.rotated_by(p) calculates p q."""
        w = other[0]*self[0] - other[1]*self[1] - other[2]*self[2] - other[3]*self[3]
        x = other[0]*self[1] + other[1]*self[0] + other[2]*self[3] - other[3]*self[2]
        y = other[0]*self[2] - other[1]*self[3] + other[2]*self[0] + other[3]*self[1]
        z = other[0]*self[3] + other[1]*self[2] - other[2]*self[1] + other[3]*self[0]
        n = sqrt(w*w + x*x + y*y + z*z)
        if n == 0:
            return tuple.__new__(Versor, (1, 0, 0, 0))
        elif n != 1:
            w /= n
            x /= n
            y /= n
            z /= n
        return tuple.__new__(Versor, (w, x, y, z))

    def transform(self, points, translate=(0, 0, 0), pretranslate=(0,0,0)):
        result = []
        pre = Vector(pretranslate[0], pretranslate[1], pretranslate[2])
        post = Vector(translate[0], translate[1], translate[2])
        for p in points:
            result.append(self.rotate(Vector(p) + pre) + post)
        return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from random import Random
    rng = Random()

    N = 10

    # Cumulative inverse rotations and local translations
    R = []
    T = []
    for i in range(0, N):
        while True:
            x = rng.uniform(-1,+1)
            y = rng.uniform(-1,+1)
            z = rng.uniform(-1,+1)
            n = sqrt(x*x + y*y + z*z)
            if n > 0.1 and n < 1.0:
                break
        R.append(Versor.from_axis_angle(Vector(x, y, z), rng.uniform(-180, 180)))
        T.append(Vector(rng.uniform(-2,+2), rng.uniform(-2,+2), rng.uniform(-2,+2)))

    n = N - 1

    # Valid range for k is 0..N, inclusive.
    k = round(rng.uniform(-0.49, N+0.49))

    Qa = [ None ]*(N+1)
    Qb = [ None ]*(N+1)
    Pa = [ None ]*(N+1)
    Pb = [ None ]*(N+1)

    #
    # Orientation
    #

    # a) Forwards
    Qa[0] = Versor(1,0,0,0)
    for i in range(1, N+1):     # i = 1, 2, ..., N-1, N.
        Qa[i] = Qa[i-1].rotate(R[i-1])

    # b) Backwards
    Qb[N] = Versor(1,0,0,0)
    for i in range(N-1,-1,-1):  # i = N-1, N-2, ..., 1, 0.
        Qb[i] = Qb[i+1].rotate(R[i].inverse)
      
    print("Orientation quaternions before fixup pass:")
    for i in range(0, N+1):     # i = 0, 1, ..., N-1, N.
        print("%s : %s" % (str(Qa[i]), str(Qb[i])))

    # Orientation fixup.
    QaFix = Qa[k].inverse
    QbFix = Qb[k].inverse
    for i in range(0, N+1):     # i = 0, 1, ..., N-1, N.
        Qa[i] = QaFix.rotate(Qa[i])
        Qb[i] = QbFix.rotate(Qb[i])

    #
    # Position
    #

    # a) Forwards
    Pa[0] = Vector(0,0,0)
    for i in range(1, N+1):     # i = 1, 2, ..., N-1, N.
        Pa[i] = Pa[i-1] + Qa[i-1].rotate(T[i-1])

    # b) Backwards
    Pb[N] = Vector(0,0,0)
    for i in range(N-1,-1,-1):  # i = N-1, N-2, ..., 1, 0.
        Pb[i] = Pb[i+1] - Qb[i].rotate(T[i])

    # Position fixup.
    PaFix = Pa[k]
    PbFix = Pb[k]
    for i in range(0, N+1):     # i = 0, 1, ..., N-1, N.
        Pa[i] = Pa[i] - PaFix
        Pb[i] = Pb[i] - PbFix

    print("Orientation quaternions after fixup pass for k=%d:" % k)
    qerr = [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
    perr = [ 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
    for i in range(0, N+1):     # i = 0, 1, ..., N-1, N.
        print("%s = %s   %s = %s" % (str(Qa[i]), str(Qb[i]), str(Pa[i]), str(Pb[i])))
        qerr = [ max(qerr[0], abs(Qa[i][0] - Qb[i][0])),
                 max(qerr[1], abs(Qa[i][1] - Qb[i][1])),
                 max(qerr[2], abs(Qa[i][2] - Qb[i][2])),
                 max(qerr[3], abs(Qa[i][3] - Qb[i][3])) ]
        perr = [ max(perr[0], abs(Pa[0] - Pb[0])),
                 max(perr[1], abs(Pa[1] - Pb[1])),
                 max(perr[2], abs(Pa[2] - Pb[2])) ]

    print("Max errors: %.6f %.6f %.6f %.6f   %.6f %.6f %.6f" % (*qerr, *perr))
```

When run, the program generates ten rotations and translations, and uses the two iteration directions to solve $Q_i$ and $P_i$ with a random $k$.

The output contains first $Q_a^\prime$ and $Q_b^\prime$ before the fixup pass, then $Q_a$, $Q_b$, $P_a$, and $P_b$.  If this approach works, then $Q_a = Q_b$ and $P_a = P_b$, with a selected row ($k = 0$ being the first) having $Q_a = Q_b = 1$ and $P_a = P_b = \vec{0}$.
The last line reports the maximum component-wise differences between each pair of $Q_a$, $Q_b$ and $P_a$, $P_b$.

Here is the output from an example run:

```
Orientation quaternions before fixup pass:
( 1.00000; 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000) : ( 0.77039;-0.19139,-0.58682,-0.15973)
( 0.41966;-0.19167,-0.83338, 0.30435) : (-0.15381;-0.53969,-0.79943, 0.21446)
( 0.69413; 0.48687,-0.52190, 0.09363) : ( 0.33662; 0.10393,-0.86924, 0.34685)
( 0.77771; 0.49771,-0.37579,-0.07897) : ( 0.46126; 0.22090,-0.84049, 0.17893)
( 0.92556; 0.28991,-0.23517,-0.06307) : ( 0.62045; 0.04565,-0.78269, 0.01871)
(-0.24442; 0.33496,-0.88851,-0.19650) : (-0.67698; 0.27822,-0.63217, 0.25427)
( 0.40926; 0.48004,-0.01805,-0.77572) : ( 0.27267; 0.74382,-0.47920,-0.37783)
(-0.34109; 0.24307,-0.89218,-0.16908) : (-0.76681; 0.20925,-0.55835, 0.23762)
(-0.48096; 0.51707, 0.30692,-0.63805) : (-0.19338; 0.91384, 0.31398,-0.17004)
( 0.45215; 0.51974, 0.68178, 0.24620) : ( 0.88721; 0.27829, 0.22401, 0.29195)
( 0.77039; 0.19139, 0.58682, 0.15973) : ( 1.00000; 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000)
Orientation quaternions after fixup pass for k=5:
(-0.24442;-0.33496, 0.88851, 0.19650) = (-0.24442;-0.33496, 0.88851, 0.19650)   (-0.36075, 0.15348,-3.62981) = (-0.36075, 0.15348,-3.62981)
( 0.51388; 0.34046, 0.64085, 0.45752) = ( 0.51388; 0.34046, 0.64085, 0.45752)   ( 0.47612,-0.59985,-2.00515) = ( 0.47612,-0.59985,-2.00515)
( 0.43873;-0.16576, 0.87133,-0.14426) = ( 0.43873;-0.16576, 0.87133,-0.14426)   ( 0.18914,-0.35767,-1.86871) = ( 0.18914,-0.35767,-1.86871)
( 0.32603;-0.37848, 0.85420,-0.14422) = ( 0.32603;-0.37848, 0.85420,-0.14422)   ( 1.60830,-2.51529,-2.32274) = ( 1.60830,-2.51529,-2.32274)
( 0.09222;-0.39072, 0.91569, 0.01848) = ( 0.09222;-0.39072, 0.91569, 0.01848)   ( 0.61687,-1.03912,-1.88966) = ( 0.61687,-1.03912,-1.88966)
( 1.00000; 0.00000, 0.00000,-0.00000) = ( 1.00000; 0.00000,-0.00000, 0.00000)   ( 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000) = ( 0.00000, 0.00000, 0.00000)
( 0.22923;-0.94011, 0.20253,-0.15045) = ( 0.22923;-0.94011, 0.20253,-0.15045)   ( 1.83789,-0.53006,-0.60693) = ( 1.83789,-0.53006,-0.60693)
( 0.99072; 0.07993,-0.09386, 0.05718) = ( 0.99072; 0.07993,-0.09386, 0.05718)   ( 2.73874,-2.16200,-1.44103) = ( 2.73874,-2.16200,-1.44103)
( 0.14344;-0.59250,-0.61448,-0.50078) = ( 0.14344;-0.59250,-0.61448,-0.50078)   ( 2.76191,-1.35384,-0.52793) = ( 2.76191,-1.35384,-0.52793)
(-0.59057;-0.19371, 0.41969,-0.66149) = (-0.59057;-0.19371, 0.41969,-0.66149)   ( 4.10824,-0.82590,-2.47648) = ( 4.10824,-0.82590,-2.47648)
(-0.67698;-0.27822, 0.63217,-0.25427) = (-0.67698;-0.27822, 0.63217,-0.25427)   ( 5.38527,-3.28029,-2.42548) = ( 5.38527,-3.28029,-2.42548)
Max errors: 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000   0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Hopefully this suffices as a numerical proof that this approach works.

Comment: Got it! Here is the solution code. https://pastebin.com/54Ticb2E

Comment: My previous update was wrong again. These are the correct update rules:

$$Q_i = Q_{i-1} R_{i-1}$$
$$X_i = X_{i-1} + Q_{i-1} T_{i-1} Q_{i-1}^{-1}$$

Comment: Thanks for updating your post -- your solution matches mine now. I appreciate your patience, and the effort you put into answering this question!

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to change the definitions -- I just had to go through an iterative process of phrasing mathematically exactly what I was trying to compute.

Comment: @LukeHutchison: No worries, that's what I did here too. It happens! :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer by "None" is the same as the answer I arrived at. I'm posting my working here:

To map $X_i$, the local coordinates of a point $X$ captured in the coordinate system of camera position $L_i$, to $X_{i-1}$, the coordinates of the point in the coordinate system of camera position $L_{i-1}$, using the known relative rotation quaternion $R_{i-1}$ and translation vector $T_{i-1}$, we can use the following equation (this is obtained directly from the definition of how these relative rotations and translations are defined):

$$X_{i-1} = R_{i-1} X_i R_{i-1}^{-1} + T_{i-1}\tag{1}$$

So to map $X_i$ (in the coordinate system of $L_i$) to $X_{i-2}$ (in the coordinate system of $L_{i-2}$), we obtain:

$$X_{i-2} = R_{i-2} (R_{i-1} X_i R_{i-1}^{-1} + T_{i-1}) R_{i-2}^{-1} + T_{i-2}$$

$$= (R_{i-2} R_{i-1} X_i R_{i-1}^{-1} R_{i-2}^{-1}) + (R_{i-2} T_{i-1} R_{i-2}^{-1} + T_{i-2})$$

where the lefthand operand of the toplevel addition is the "rotation part" and the righthand operand is the "translation part".

Similarly, to map $X_i$ (in the coordinate system of $L_i$) to $X_{i-3}$ (in the coordinate system of $L_{i-3}$), we obtain:

$$X_{i-3} = R_{i-3} ((R_{i-2} R_{i-1} X_i R_{i-1}^{-1} R_{i-2}^{-1}) + (R_{i-2} T_{i-1} R_{i-2}^{-1} + T_{i-2})) R_{i-3}^{-1} +T_{i-3}$$

$$= R_{i-3} (R_{i-2} R_{i-1} X_i R_{i-1}^{-1} R_{i-2}^{-1}) R_{i-3}^{-1} + R_{i-3} (R_{i-2} T_{i-1} R_{i-2}^{-1} + T_{i-2}) R_{i-3}^{-1} +T_{i-3}$$

$$ = (R_{i-3} R_{i-2} R_{i-1} X_i R_{i-1}^{-1} R_{i-2}^{-1} R_{i-3}^{-1}) + (R_{i-3} R_{i-2} T_{i-1} R_{i-2}^{-1} R_{i-3}^{-1} + (R_{i-3} T_{i-2} R_{i-3}^{-1} +T_{i-3}))$$

We want to compute $X_0$, the global coordinates of $X_i$, i.e. the coordinates of $X_i$ in the coordinate system of camera location $L_0$. Here $Q_i$ and $P_i$ represent the orientation quaternion and translation vector respectively for the camera position $L_i$ *in the coordinate system of $L_0$*:

$$X_0 = Q_i X_i Q_i^{-1} + P_i\tag{2}$$

This yields the following orientation and position update rules:

$$Q_i = Q_{i-1}R_{i-1} \, \, \, ; \, \, \, Q_0 = 1\tag{3}$$
$$P_i = Q_{i-1} T_{i-1} Q_{i-1}^{-1} + P_{i-1} \, \, \, ; \, \, \,P_0 = [0 \,\, 0 \,\, 0]\tag{4}$$

So we started from a transformation mapping $X_i$ to $X_{i-1}$ (Eq. 1), and ended up with a pair of transformations mapping $Q_{i-1}$ to $Q_{i}$ and $P_{i-1}$ to $P_i$ (Eqs. 2, 3), i.e. $P_i$ and $Q_i$ can be computed incrementally, in a sequence starting from $\langle P_0, Q_0 \rangle$ and ending with $\langle P_i, Q_i \rangle$. The transformations $Q_i$ and $P_i$ can then be used to map $X_i$ back to $X_0$ (Eq. 2).